# How to include js and css in Zend Form Elements?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I create my own zend form element - App_Form_Element_Wysiwyg

```
<?php

class App_Form_Element_Wysiwyg extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml
{
    /**
     * Default form view helper to use for rendering
     * @var string
     */
    public $helper = 'wysiwyg';

}
```

Then I create helper for wysiwyg - App_View_Helper_Wysiwyg

```
<?php

class App_View_Helper_Wysiwyg extends Zend_View_Helper_FormTextarea
{
    public function wysiwyg($name, $value = null, $attribs = null)
    {
        // Here I want to include js and css for wysiwyg editor
        ...
        $xhtml = '<textarea name="' . $this->view->escape($name) . '"'
                . ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '"'
                . $disabled
                . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs) . '>'
                . $this->view->escape($value) . '</textarea>';

        return $xhtml;
    }
}
```

How can I include js and css files for wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `headScript()` helper lets you add or manipulate script tags in the header. So within your helper you can do:

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/path/to/file.js');
```

then just ensure your layout is calling the helper somewhere in the head section:

```
<?=$this->headScript()?>
```

to output the HTML. There is also the `headStyle()` helper which works in a similar way and can be used for your CSS.

Relevant docs:

- [HeadScript](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript)
- [HeadStyle](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headstyle)

Comment: Thank you, it works. But what if I want to use AJAX and there is no head tag in server response, only json with html of the form and pathes to js and css. Is there a method to get pathes to js and css from form?

Comment: If you're parsing the AJAX response as JSON, it can't 'run' anything. But the JS code that is making the AJAX request can add JS and CSS to your page head. Exactly how to do this depends a bit how you are making your AJAX request.

Comment: I make AJAX request, parse JSON, and if there exists js property I include js files or js code, if there exists css property I include css files.